# In c# how to write text over an image in a datagridview

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

I have a `dataGridView` in my form and each column is a `DataGridViewImageColumn` In each cell there's a JPG which i load from ressources like this :

```
Image H1 = Properties.Ressources.H1_T;
dgMap[6, 0].Value = H1;
```

So each cell contains an image, my question is how do i put text over it? I just want to put a ✔ mark on the top right corner.

Also i have another question, is it still possible to highlight the selected cell containing an image?

EDIT:

I found a way just overlaying another image with a checkmark...

```
Image primaryImage = (Image)dgMap[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(primaryImage))
        {
            using (Image overlayDone = Properties.Resources.done) 
            {
                graphics.DrawImage(overlayDone, new Point(0, 0));
            }
        }

        dgMap[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = primaryImage;
```

So my question is how to highlight the selected cell? As it's an image there's no selection visible to the user

Answer (score 0):

While there might be a variety of solutions to do this, personnaly instead of using plain image control, I used buttons with a custom behavior derived from the standard WPF button. This way I could display text over it, and easily click it and highlight the selected image.

EDIT:
You can tweak a highlight effect using the `DropShadowEffect`.
Add this behavior to the user click:

```
            DropShadowEffect SelectedEffect = new DropShadowEffect
        {
            Color = new Color { A = 0, R = 255, G = 0, B = 0 },
            Direction = 320,
            ShadowDepth = 1,
            Opacity = 1,
            RenderingBias = RenderingBias.Quality
        };
```

Comment: I overlayed another image with a checkmark and it's good to go. But still searching how to hightlight the cell when a user clicks on it ^^

Comment: I'm having some difficulties finding back how I did it before, I'll edit my answer soon. But just to be sure, this is an image control that needs to be highlighted right?

Comment: It's a cell inside a datagridview. The column is of type DataGridViewImageColumn. The cell contains an image.

Comment: I don't get your answer. Are you sure you can do something like that to a single cell inside a gridview?

Comment: Well then I need more information, how do you feel your DataGrid? What element is dealing with the click behavior?